# When does LAContext:evaluatePolicy result in LAError.AppCancel?

Tags: ios, ios9, touch-id

Is it possible for an app to cancel the touch id prompt shown on LAContext - evaluatePolicy(_:localizedReason:reply:)
.

The documentation for enum LAError has a new case for iOS9 - case AppCancel. The header documentation clearly says that this is returned when the authentication was cancelled by the application. But I cannot find any reference to how to make an app to cancel the authentication.

When is LAError.AppCancel returned by the evaluatePolicy call?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to phone your device to cancel the fingerprint verification.